# How to use the same SSIS Data Flow with different Date Values?

Tags: ssis

I have a very straightforward SSIS package containing one data flow which is comprised of an OLEDB source and a flat file destination.  The OLEDB source calls a query that takes 2 sets of parameters. I've mapped the parameters to Date/Time variables.

I would like to know how best to pass 4 different sets of dates to the variables and use those values in my query?

I've experimented with the For Each Loop Container using an item enumerator.  However, that does not seem to work and the package throws a System.IO.IOException error.

My container is configured as follows:
[image: Item Enumerator]
[image: Variable Mapping]
Note that both variables are of the Date/Time data type.

How can I pass 4 separate value sets to the same variables and use each variable pair to run my data flow?

Comment: What are the data types of `startDate` and `endDAte2018`?

Comment: @billinkc They are both Date/Time data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setup

I created a table and populated it with contiguous data for your sample set

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.SO_67439692;
CREATE TABLE dbo.SO_67439692
(
    SurrogateKey int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,   ActionDate date
);

INSERT INTO
    dbo.SO_67439692
(
    ActionDate
)
SELECT
    TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-12-31', '2021-04-30'))
    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '2017-12-31') AS ActionDate
FROM
    sys.all_columns AS AC;
```

In my SSIS Package, I added two Variables, startDate and endDAte2018 both of type Date Time. I added an OLE DB Connection manager pointed to the database where I made the above tables.

I added a Foreach Item Enumerator, configured it for Item Enumerator and defined the columns there as datetime as well

[image]

I populated it (what a clunky editor) with the year ranges from 2018 to 2020 as shown and 2021-01-01 to 2021-04-30.

I wired the variables up as shown in the problem definition and ran it as is. No IO error reported.

Once I knew my foreach container was working, the data flow was trivial.

I added a data flow inside the foreach loop with an OLE DB Source using a parameterized query like so

```
DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date;
SELECT  @StartDate = ?, @EndDate = ?;

SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.SO_67439692 AS S
WHERE
    S.ActionDate >= @StartDate AND S.ActionDate <= @EndDate;
```

I mapped my two variables in as parameter names of 0 and 1 and ran it.

[image]

The setup you described works great. Either there is more to your problem than stated or there's something else misaligned. Follow along with my repro and compare it to what you've built and you should see where things are "off"

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to use the same approach without defining a database table?  That is, I want the variables solely defined in the SSIS package without reliance on a database for the values.

Comment: My database table was to simulate yours `The OLEDB source calls a query that takes 2 sets of parameters` I populated with data just to ensure I had boundary conditions as expected. Substitute your table and your columns there to make it work for your use case. Biggest challenge people run into is getting parameters to align on the ForEach loop.